JavaScript SetInterval toggle between Heads and Tails
I am writing a simple coin toss script. I want to animate between Heads and Tails for 1 second before the result is output. I am using a SetInterval. I want the display to change between Heads and Tails every time the SetInterval runs. Here is the code I have
let rollingAnimator = setInterval( ()=> {
    image.src = "heads.png";
    //the next time, it should do
    //image.src = "tails.png";
}, 100);

Thanks in advance.
I am able to use Math.random() to randomly display Heads or Tails. But that's not what I want. I want it to alternate between Heads and Tails.

Save current state and flip on next run?

image.src = (image.src === "heads.png") ? "heads.png" : "tails.png"

alternate between Heads and Tails every 1 second (1000 milliseconds), updating the image source accordingly.
currentState will help keep track of the current state (heads or tails)
let currentState = "Heads";
image.src = "heads.png";

let rollingAnimator = setInterval(() => {
   if (currentState === "Heads") {
      image.src = "tails.png";
      currentState = "Tails";
   } else {
      image.src = "heads.png";
      currentState = "Heads";
   }
 }, 1000);


@Salim did this answer your question? If so please consider "accepting" it.
